# how can i dispatch 1 second later in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux

i'm using native with redux saga

if i press onLike button i want to dispatch 1 second later

do i have to use settimeout? what are the option do i have??

is there any way not using settimeout but using redux-saga

this is my code

(Explain.js)

```
    const Explain = ({navigation,route}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const {me} = useSelector((state) =>state.user);
      const {singlePost} = useSelector((state) => state.post);



      const onLike = () => {
        return dispatch({
            type: LIKE_POST_REQUEST,
            data: singlePost?.id,
        }),
        
        dispatch({
            type: LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
            data:singlePost.id
            })
        
        }
        
        
        const onUnlike = () => {
        return dispatch({
            type: UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST,
            data: singlePost?.id,
        }),
        
        dispatch({
            type: LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
            data:singlePost.id
            })
        
        }


      

      const liked = singlePost?.Likers.find((v) => v.id === me?.id);

        return (
    <Container>
      <Hi>
          안녕
      </Hi>


      {  liked       
        ?  
        <MenuContainer  onPress={onUnlike}  >
        <IconButtonU iconName="favorite"
            style={{width:23, height:23}}
            source={require('../../Assets/Images/Tabs/heart.png')}
            />
    </MenuContainer>
        :   
        <MenuContainer  onPress={onLike}  >
        <IconButtonU iconName="favorite"
            source={require('../../Assets/Images/Tabs/ic_favorite_outline.png')}
            />
            </MenuContainer>
          }


    <LikeNumber>
      좋아요{' '}
      {singlePost?.Likers.length }
    </LikeNumber>


      

      </Container>

        );
    };

    export default Explain;
```

(saga/post.js)

```
                import axios from 'axios';
                import { all, fork, put, takeLatest, throttle, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

                import {

                     LOAD_POST_FAILURE,
                     LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
                     LOAD_POST_SUCCESS,

                     LIKE_POST_FAILURE,
                     LIKE_POST_REQUEST,
                     LIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
                
                     UNLIKE_POST_FAILURE,
                     UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST,
                     UNLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
                } from '../reducers/post';



                function likePostAPI(data) {
                     return axios.patch(`/post/${data}/like`);
                }
                
                function* likePost(action) {
                     try {
                     const result = yield call(likePostAPI, action.data);
                     yield put({
                     type: LIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
                     data: result.data,
                     });
                     } catch (err) {
                     console.error(err);
                     yield put({
                     type: LIKE_POST_FAILURE,
                     error: err.response.data,
                     });
                     }
                }
                
                function unlikePostAPI(data) {
                     return axios.delete(`/post/${data}/like`);
                }
                
                function* unlikePost(action) {
                     try {
                     const result = yield call(unlikePostAPI, action.data);
                     yield put({
                     type: UNLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
                     data: result.data,
                     });
                     } catch (err) {
                     console.error(err);
                     yield put({
                     type: UNLIKE_POST_FAILURE,
                     error: err.response.data,
                     });
                     }
                }
                
                
                
                function loadPostAPI(data) {
                     return axios.get(`/post/${data}`);
                }
                
                function* loadPost(action) {
                     try {
                     const result = yield call(loadPostAPI, action.data);
                     yield put({
                     type: LOAD_POST_SUCCESS,
                     data: result.data,
                     });
                     } catch (err) {
                     console.error(err);
                     yield put({
                     type: LOAD_POST_FAILURE,
                     error: err.response.data,
                     });
                     }
                }



                function* watchUploadImages() {

                
                function* watchLoadPost() {
                     yield takeLatest(LOAD_POST_REQUEST, loadPost);
                }
                
                function* watchLikePost() {
                     yield takeLatest(LIKE_POST_REQUEST, likePost);
                }
                
                function* watchUnlikePost() {
                     yield takeLatest(UNLIKE_POST_REQUEST, unlikePost);
                }
                

                

                




                export default function* postSaga() {
                     yield all([
                
                     fork(watchLikePost),
                     fork(watchUnlikePost),
                     fork(watchLoadPost),
                     ]);
                }
```

but i don't want to use settimeout. is bacause it feels like slow so what is the best way??.....